# Get count and height of Html.ListBoxFor item

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

Using

- C#
- MVC 5
- Razor 3

I have a Html.ListBoxFor...

```
          @Html.ListBoxFor(
            x => x.sunSelectedList,
            Model.sunList,
            new { @class = "eligibleAvailableListBox" }
            )
```

I have jQuery javascript..

```
@section Scripts {
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {

        var ssList = $("#sunSelectedList");

        // the variable above is valid and contains all items

    });
</script>
}
```

With the variable ssList, how do I get the count of options and the client height of each item?

Comment: You should post the rendered HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the number of options

```
var options = $("#sunSelectedList").children('option');
var optionCount = options.length;
```

To get the height of each option use [.height()](http://api.jquery.com/height/) or [.outerHeight()](http://api.jquery.com/outerheight/)

```
options.each(function(index, item) {
  var optionHeight = $(this).outerHeight();  // includes padding and borders
}
```

**Edit**

From the documentation, *"All option elements are considered hidden, regardless of their selected state."* so `.height()` or `.outerHeight()` will in fact always return `0`. Using `window.getComputedStyle(this,null).lineHeight;` is not reliable as Chrome may return `normal` rather that a number. A possible workaround is to copy the contents of the option into a temporary `div` element and calculate the height.

```
options.each(function(index, item) {
  var temp = $('<div></div>').text($(this).text());
  $('body').append(temp);
  console.log(temp.height());
  // or
  console.log(window.getComputedStyle(temp[0], null).height);
  temp.remove();
});
```

Comment: Length works. The height calc does not; outerHeight always returns 0 as does outerHeight(true). However, upon inspection, $(this).context.currentStyle.lineHeight does give 1.4285 - which I imagine is in em? Should I use that?

Comment: actually... window.getComputedStyle(this,null).lineHeight reports "20.28px" - can I use that?

Comment: Turns out that jquery reports all `option` elements as hidden (even if they are visible on the screen) which is why `.height()` returns `0`. Using `lineHeight` if not reliable as Chrome for instance may return `normal` rather that a number. I'll edit my answer to include a possible workaround but I have not tested it enough to know how reliable it is

Comment: I used your edit with the Temp div & itemHeight = temp.height(); optionTotalHeight += itemHeight + 5; Safari, Opera and Chrome needed 5 extra pixels to show the list boxes exactly the right size (no need of scrollbars). IE & FireFox only need 3 extra pixels per item to show the list boxes perfectly. The function window.getComputedStyle with height or lineHeight returns a more accurate "15.61px" but you then also need to use parseFloat as it's a text value. I wish I could debug with Chrome as default browser in VS 2013 to see what those returned values are...

Comment: I tried to edit your function for height to close the function with ); (2 characters)- just for syntax correction - but am not allowed to save an edit for less than 6 characters...lol